# Is using Laravel api_token authentication not like storing password in plain text?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I want to validate my RESTful API using token authentication. Two key options provided are https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth and Laravel's own inbuilt token authentication.

I'm unable to make `jwt-auth` work for me even if it looks the most promising, so I decide to check on Laravel's implementation.

It is pretty straightforward. Create an extra field api_token in users DB, generate a random string and store it against the users record IN PLAIN TEXT, then any request the user sends they should append the api_token, which you shall authenticate by checking its existence in the DB. Just that.

Isn't that like storing passwords in plain text because anyone who happens to have access to the DB is as good as authenticated? Isn't there an outright security risk there? Someone help me understand this one.

Also, how does one handle things like invalidating the token, giving the token an expiry period, and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Similar Case I am not using any external plugin, while Laravel already ship a project called Lumen which is best suitable for Restfull web service,

I am storing the encrypted hash string as api_token in the user table, 
and in my mobile application i let the users authenticate by username password first time and then i store the decrypted token in the mobile to maintain the user state for subsequent api calls, key point is i am storing the decrypted user token in the mobile and whenver i receive the token in server, i do comparison to match both of them using the same encryption function i have used before,...

in this case you have to come up with your own encryption algorithm since you need to use the same algorithm to decry-pt in the client,
or else an easy way is to copy the user password hash string in the api_token field and store the user password in the client side, 
but you have to make sure the security of the client application,

if you consider native android, i will use sharedpreference in private mode which is secure....

```
  if(Hash::check($password,$user->password)){
                $response['success'] = 1;
                $response['message'] = 'You have Connected to Server Successfully';
                $response['api_token'] = $user->api_token;
            }else{
                $response['success'] = 0;
                $response['message'] = 'Authentication Unsuccessful';
                $response['api_token'] = '';
            }
```

Comment: so the difference between what you are doing and what Laravel is offering is that you are encrypting/hashing your  `api_token` before you store it in the DB? Is there a way one is able to customise the Laravel API Token authentication so that you do compare the submitted api_token to the hashed one in your DB? Or that's where I have to create a custom auth service?

Comment: check my answer, i updated it with sample code, so what i would suggest you is two option,
1. Come up with your own algorithm to encrypt/decrypt the api_token.
2. store the hashed password of the user in the api_token field as well,
   and from client application you can let the user authenticate by username,password first time and then store the real password and pass it to server every time, and compare it as in the example code

Comment: again i suggest you, you must be sure that the client application 100% secure to store the plain credentials of user , otherwise its like you would open a security whole to your application,

Comment: okay, let me have a look a that approach and evaluate its use-case on my side.